# How to extend a Javascript Lib to use the same config everytime

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using [`dataTables`](https://datatables.net/) to show several different kinds of data in my app. Every time I want a table I need to call the method and pass the translation object together with:

```
oTable = $('.dTables').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "sDom": '<""l>t<"F"fp>',
        "columnDefs": [{
            "targets": 0,
            "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
                var livro = data.split(';');
                return '<a href="/livro/ver/'+ livro[0] +'">'+ livro[1] +'</a>';
            }
        }],
        "language": {
            "search": "Buscar: ",
            "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ itens por p&aacute;gina",
            "zeroRecords": "Nenhum registro",
            "info": "Mostrando _PAGE_ p&aacute;ginas de _PAGES_",
        }
    });
```

Is there anyway to extend the `dataTable` object to Always use the same object so I don't have to repeat my code over and over again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to have the `language` property (or some other specific properties) be the same for the different tables in your application, [the documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/options) suggests extending `$.fn.dataTable.defaults`. Using your `language` option:

```
$.extend(true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
    "language": {
        "search": "Buscar: ",
        "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ itens por p&aacute;gina",
        "zeroRecords": "Nenhum registro",
        "info": "Mostrando _PAGE_ p&aacute;ginas de _PAGES_",
    }
});
```

Then when you create tables in your application, you do not need to define `language` in your options object, only the properties for the options needed for that specific table. This is an appropriate solution for setting defaults for most of the options.

Comment: That was exactly what I wanted, thanks! How did you know that `$.fn.dataTable.defaults`? Is it the same for any library? And how does `$.extend()` Works? Is it from jQuery? Thank you

Comment: [The documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/options) mentions it as a way to set defaults (added link to answer), and it probably varies from library to library. [`$.extend()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) is from jQuery, and it copies all of the properties from the second object onto the first object. The first argument (`true`) specifies that it should be a [deep copy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy).

Answer (score 1):

Sure just create a config object

```
var dTableConfig ={
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "sDom": '<""l>t<"F"fp>',
    "columnDefs": [{
        "targets": 0,
        "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
            var livro = data.split(';');
            return '<a href="/livro/ver/'+ livro[0] +'">'+ livro[1] +'</a>';
        }
    }],
    "language": {
        "search": "Buscar: ",
        "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ itens por p&aacute;gina",
        "zeroRecords": "Nenhum registro",
        "info": "Mostrando _PAGE_ p&aacute;ginas de _PAGES_",
    }
}
```

Then pass that variable to initialization of plugin:

```
oTable = $('.dTables').dataTable( dTableConfig );
```

Then if you have instances where you need slightly different configuration can do things like:

```
var specialConfig = {
   "bJQueryUI": false
}

var specialTableOptions = $.extend(true,{}, dTableConfig , specialConfig);

specialTable= $('.dTables').dataTable( specialTableOptions );
```